I got tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized when trying to post using tweepy==4.14.0
Am trying to create a simple twitter bot that will be able to post and get my dm events using tweepy, but i get "Unauthorized" every time i tried to post.
Am using tweepy==4.14.0 and bellow are my codes and Basic plan
import os
import tweepy
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

BEARER_TOKEN  = os.getenv('TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN')
API_KEY = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY')
API_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')
TWITTER_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID')
TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET')


client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=API_KEY, consumer_secret=API_SECRET_KEY, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN, access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key=API_KEY, consumer_secret=API_SECRET_KEY)
api = tweepy.API(auth=auth)

client.create_tweet(text="God is Good", user_auth=True)

I was expecting to see the post in my twitter account page
